# Picasa android api

Tags: android, picasa

I would really appreciate any WORKING example, which tells me how to connect to the Picasa from Android in a step-by-step way. I have browsed Internet and downloading tons of git repositories with examples for three days always finding Deprecated, not working or not Android examples, or even broken links. Only thing I have learned is, that I'm completely lost. It's a very bad surprise to me, that there is not any example of "How to build a basic gallery app in Android using non-deprecated methods".

V.K.